# General approach to simplify equations of the form $f(x)=g(f(x-1))$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

As an example lets say:

$f(x)=g(f(x-1))$ where x is the set of Integers greater than or equal to 2

$g(x)=3x-1$ $\forall$ $x\geq1$
and $f(1)=1$

How do we simplify $f(x)$ in terms of $x$?

The question can also be intrpeted as finding $t_n$ in terms of $n$ subject to:

$t_n=3t_{n-1}-1$

$t_1=1$

where $t_n$ forms the $n^{th}$ term of a series

Answer (score 1):

Your way of writing it with the difference equation, i.e, $$t_n=3t_{n-1}-1\ \text{with}\ t_1=1$$
Is in fact the correct way of talking about this problem. Using the notations $f(x),g(x)$ etc. makes it look like this is a continuous, rather than discrete, problem. Also, we usually call the first term $t_0$, not $t_1$, unless it is especially convenient to use $1$ as the starting index, and it is usually written with $n$ and $n+1$, like this: $$t_{n+1}=3t_{n}-1\ \text{with}\ t_0=1$$
With that out of the way, let's actually talk about this difference equation. Unfortunately there is no general method to simplify these sorts of equations to explicit functions of $n$, just as there is no general method for solving integrals or differential equations. However it turns out that this sort of difference equation, called an [Arithmetico-Geometric Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) is actually solvable, and this particular one has the solution $$t_n=\frac{1}{2}(3^n-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=g(f(x-1))$

**Now if you use the function of g we get**

$f(x) = 3f(x-1) - 1$

**Putting the value $x=1$ in this equation
We get the following values as**

$f(2) = 2$

$f(3) = 5$

$f(4) = 14$

$f(5) = 41$

$f(6) = 365$

**Now you can do the rest of the work and find a function for  $f$**.

**Hope it help.**